# Reading lines and looping over a file object

Tags: python

I'm trying to read lines from a file and print them in a loop which works, but I get newlines after every print statement.

Here is my class

```
class FileReader:
    """Reads a file from args"""
    def __init__(self, args):
        input = ''
        with open(args, 'r') as rFile:
            for line in rFile:
                print(line)
```

My input file is like this. (The '$'s are new lines):

```
12 3$
2$
9$
5$
3 4$
```

My output becomes:

```
12 3

2

9

5

3 4
```

What is the reason I'm getting those spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you loop over a file, the lines yielded include the newline at the end of the line. Using `print()` outputs those lines with an *extra* newline.

You can use `.strip()` to remove whitespace from the start and end of the line, including the newline.

If you *only* want to remove the newline at the end, use `line[:-1]` or `line.rstrip('\n')` to remove it.

Last but not least, you can also tell `print()` not to add a newline:

```
print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `print` command automatically adds a newline at the end. Since your files already have a newline at the end of each line (by definition), your program will output two newlines consecutively.

For example, try this:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    print(str(i) + '\n')
```

You will obtain something with the same "problem" as your code.

If you want to fix that behavior, replace `print(line)` with `print(line.rstrip())`, which will strip the all white-space characters from the end of each line. If your lines end with tabs or spaces, this might be problematic; in that case, use `print line.rstrip('\n')`, which will only remove newline characters.

Comment: Note that some files use line feed + carriage return = two characters. Better use `line.rstrip()`.

Comment: The OP is probably using Python 3, as `print()` is used as a function.

Comment: @moooeeeep: good point. I edited the answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @moooeeeep: if the file isn't opened in binary mode, the newlines will be treated sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the new line, use rstrip. E.g.:

```
print(line.rstrip())
```